# Creating a Lookup Constraint

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I have 2 tables, as follows (only significant colmns and data shown...):

```
table 'TACI'        table 'Statuses'
fields
StatusID            ID
——————————————————————————————————
0                   0
...                 ...
```

I've run:

```
ALTER TABLE TACI
    ADD StatusID INT;
```

(execute)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TACI
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STATUS
    FOREIGN KEY (ID)
    REFERENCES dbo.Statuses (ID);
```

(execute)

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_STATUS". 
>   The conflict occurred in database "TIL", table "dbo.Statuses", column 'ID'.

It would be nice to know what the conflict is...

```
Statuses.ID   is (PK, int, not null)
TACI.StatusID is (int  not null).
```

I created `StatusID` 'null' then altered it to 'not null' when I got the error. 
Made no difference.

Comment: The error is that you have at least one column in TACI.ID that does not exist in Statuses.ID.

Comment: I'm thinking you meant `FOREIGN KEY (StatusID) REFERENCES dbo.Statuses(ID)`, not `FOREIGN KEY (ID)`.

Comment: Is the second table name 'status' or 'statuses'?

Comment: Statuses. Corrected, above.